# How to pass variables using AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, post

Here is my JS code:

```
   function info(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'doSomething.php',
        data:'text='+encodeURIComponent($('.text').html())
            +'&info1='+encodeURIComponent($('.info1').html())
            +'&info2='+encodeURIComponent($('.info2').html())
            +'&info3='+encodeURIComponent($('.info3').html())
            +'&var1='+$('#var1').val()
            +'&var2='+$('#var2').val()
            +'&var3='+$('#var3').val(),
        success:function(){$('.action').fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500)}
    });
    //alert("info - did something, great!");
    return false;
    };
```

Everything works and is passed to doSomething.php script; except for:

- var1 var2 var3

  can any one please tell me why?
  Is there a problem with above JS, or my PHP:

I'm new to AJAX. - thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 data:{prop11:'some value',prop2:'someVal2'}
```

Comment: I need the values to come from a PHP script that calls this JS function. $var1 $var2 $var3 are echoed in the script..What do you mean? - sorry if it's obvious...

Comment: thanks for answer, but can you specify a little? How can you get 'some value' from a PHP variable? - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to use the  `$var1 $var2 $var3` variables,
but it seems you want to use it this way:

```
  function info(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'doSomething.php',
        data:'text='+encodeURIComponent($('.text').html())
            +'&info1='+encodeURIComponent($('.info1').html())
            +'&info2='+encodeURIComponent($('.info2').html())
            +'&info3='+encodeURIComponent($('.info3').html())
            +'&var1='+$var1
            +'&var2='+$var2
            +'&var3='+$var3,
        success:function(){$('.action').fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500)}
    });
    //alert("info - did something, great!");
    return false;
    };
```

**Here is a small explanation:**

- PHP is server side language.

It gets the request from the user and generate the html and js files to return. If there a few usages of a variable named $var1 used inside a html/js file, they will replaced with  with its value.

The client knows nothing about it, since he get the generated html/js file.
At the client, the generated javascript will run with constant values generated by the server.

Comment: so you mean at client side $var1... will be replaced with same PHP value given to client in rest of html? even $var1... inside the JS <script>? -I'll try it and let you know...thnaks!

Comment: This is the concept, since I am not coming from PHP background I am not sure about the syntax. From a quick search in the internet I think this syntax will do:

<?php echo $var1 ?>

Let me know if it works

Comment: It works if the JS is created/parsed by PHP at server side, meaning, if the JS is inside a PHP script it works but if i include a JS file into a PHP script the server 'parser' ignores the PHP tags. - thanks! look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345457/how-to-put-php-inside-javascript

Comment: interesting...this could be very handy...thinking of switching JS file extensions into PHP, might make JS files unreadable to prying eyes outside of 'parsed' html scripts...got to run some tests....

Comment: about hiding JS look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288790/how-to-make-js-code-invisible